# Scala type parameters by declaring the type inside the function

Tags: function, scala, type-parameter

I'm just starting to learn Scala, coming from a Java background. I have been trying to understand type parameters in functions and inference of types. This is a standard example in the Scala docs:

```
class Decorator(left: String, right: String) {
  def layout[A](x: A) = left + x.toString() + right
}

object FunTest extends Application {
  def apply(f: Int => String, v: Int) = f(v)
  val decorator = new Decorator("[", "]")
  println(apply(decorator.layout, 7))
}
```

If I try to apply a type parameter to the `apply` function and keep `v` a strong type, a type mismatch occurs. Why doesn't the type get inferred here?

```
def apply[B](f: B => String, v: String) = f(v) //Type mismatch
def apply[B](f: B => String, v: B) = f(v)      //Works fine
```

Thanks

Comment: I think it is because B is inferred not when you define "apply", but when you call it. (Wild guess) Would make sense that B is not instantiated because f is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at `apply` without it's body:

```
 def apply[B](f: B => String, v: String)
```

That reads "`apply` is a function (method) parameterized on a type `B`, that takes a function from `B` to `String`, and a `String`".

Think of `B` as a type variable; it will need to be instantiated at some point. That point is **not** the declaration of `apply`. It is when apply is, well, applied to ;-)

By this contract, usage like this must be allowed:

```
 def g(i: Int): String = "i is " + i

 apply(g, "foo")  // Here the type variable `B` is "instantiated" to the type Int,
```

But given that you have a body like `f(v)`, just substituting, we see the contradiction:

Substitute

```
 f(v)
```

With

```
 g("foo") // can't compile; g takes a B, which is an Int
```

Comment: Great explanation, thanks. Does this mean that the error is more of a contract error, but could work in theory if you entered `g:(i: String)`?

Comment: No, it's not a contract error in that sense. It's a compile error because you are asking the compiler to make a contract that is contradictory.  Parameterizing on `[B]` means that the actual type that `B` represents depends on usage and this `apply` must handle *any* `g: B => String`; this contradicts `apply`'s implementation which passes a `String` to `g`, which takes a `B` not necessarily a String.